# Fast Switching For UPS

Tags: power-supply, switches, relay, ups

Well I don't even know how to call this question, but the point is. I am making a DC UPS, and I want to be able to quickly switch from the wall supply to the battery supply, and I don't think a relay would work. BTW I'd be powering a router.

Comment: Why won't a relay work?

Comment: So, I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking", because, as you notice, you're not asking something,.

Answer (score 1):

Set your power supply voltage to be a little bit higher than the fully-charged voltage from the battery.

You need a diode from the battery + side to the router (cathode towards router).  Choose a Schottky diode if the current is more than an amp or so - the reduced voltage drop reduces the amount of heat dissipated by the diode.

Switch over will be instantaneous as soon as the original power voltage drops below the battery voltage minus the diode's forward voltage. You may need to check if the original power supply needs a diode in line too.  A small chance that the battery power could leak back into the power supply output.

Be absolutely sure the diode from the battery has the proper reverse voltage (well higher than the system's operating voltage), to prevent any current from the original supply from getting into the battery.  The diode's current rating also needs to be well higher then the maximum expected current.  Forcing current into a non-rechargeable battery can be dangerous.  Uncontrolled current into a rechargeable battery can be dangerous too.  Some commercial models use a resistor across the battery diode to trickle charge the battery. A fuse in the battery line is also a good measure.